# How to launch XSS code into an HTML input field?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

im working on trying to find vulnerabilities on a fake website for class and I was wondering how to launch XSS code into this input field?

- This is the code from the website:

```html
<form name="friendForm" method="POST" action="/Tunestore/addfriend.do">
  Friend name: <input type="text" name="friend" value="&quot
    <script>alert(1)</script>"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

- I have tried this but it didn't work:

  `"> <script>alert(1)</script>`

  `" onfocus="alert(1)"`

  `" onclick="alert(1)`

Comment: That's because your browser escapes the value you type in there. Typically XSS is achieved when the text you write into an input box is later treated as HTML an published somewhere, maybe check out [Computerphile's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L5l9lSnNMxg) on XSS.

Comment: So XSS would not be possible on this type of input?

Comment: Not like this, no

Comment: What is the way to achieve XSS with an input field like that?

Comment: As I wrote above, the text in that input field has to be treaded like HTML in a process that publishes it, let's say, you're making a blog and the comment section has a textbox. When a user hits submit you just add that comment as a `<p>` to the site, if the user then enters some html, including script tags, that JS will be executed by all clients visiting the page, not just by your own browser, which isn't really a good attack vector

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
" onfocus="alert(1)" autofocus="
```

It will expand to:

```
<'input type="text" name="friend" value=" " onfocus="alert(1)" autofocus=" " />
```

Which will cause an alert box, demonstrating XSS.

Comment: did you try methods on https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#No_closing_script_tags ?

Comment: A browser will most certainly not treat the input as HTML, it will escape the characters

Comment: Please properly format your answer, e.g. by using code blocks: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting